# Extract values from IN parameter and store it in local variables in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have `:listDate:String` IN parameter that I'm passing to my proc which contains the **dynamic values separated by ,**
 This `:listDate:String` is passed to proc from Java front end and it contains the value selected by the user

**There can be many combinations**

Case 1 `listDate`  can have
 1. 30 Dec 2013 to 05 Jan 2014
 so **`v_start_date` is 30 Dec 2013** and 
 **`v_end_date` is 05 Jan 2014**

Case 2 `listdate` can have
 
 30 Dec 2013 to 05 Jan 2014,
 
 06 Jan 2014 to 12 Jan 2014
  **so `v_start_date` is 30 Dec 2013** and 
 **`v_end_date` is 12 Jan 2014**

Case 3 `listDate` can have
 06 Jan 2014 to 12 Jan 2014,
 13 Jan 2014 to 19 Jan 2014,
 20 Jan 2014 to 26 Jan 2014

so **`v_start_date` is 06 Jan 2014** and 
 **`v_end_date` is 26 Jan 2014**

How can I extract the values as shown above into `v_start_date` and `v_end_date` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by using

```
select substring(listDate from '............$') as v_end_date,
substring(listDate from '^...............') as v_start_date
```